# Работа со строками

Tags: c#

Есть строковая переменная `s1="\text1\text2\"`.

Как путем строковых операций образовать из нее строку `s2="text2"` на с#?

Comment: а поконкртенее можно? Что за задача? О каких строковых операциях идет речь?

Comment: Разбейте строку на подстроки по символу слеш. Сделать это можно через метод string.Split('\')

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] StrArray =  s1.Split(new string[] { @"\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

А дальше просто выводите нужный элемент массива, например, так:

```
StrArray[1]
```

Можно сразу вывести нужный элемент, например, так:

```
string Str =  s1.Split(new string[] { @"\" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```